# Problematic Binding of Python Function and TKinter GUI Properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to build a GUI that takes the root directory and key phrases as inputs from the user, and output all the lines in that directory that contains the key phrases the user enters. My python function works by itself when I enter in parameters manually, but when I try to bind it to my TKinter layout, and pass in variables by using the get function from the user's input, I keep getting "None" as a result. I am relatively new to Python, thank you so much for your help!

## My TKinter Layout

```
from myFunction import myFunction 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

class Feedback:

    def __init__(self, master):

        master.title('My Python Function')
        master.resizable(False, False)
        master.configure(background = '#ffffff')

        self.frame_header = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_header.pack()

        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.configure('TFrame', background = '#ffffff')
        self.style.configure('TButton', background = '#ffffff')
        self.style.configure('TLabel', background = '#ffffff', font = ('Arial', 11))



        ttk.Label(self.frame_header, wraplength = 300, text = "Output the desired lines from the directory by entering the following.").grid(row = 0, column = 1) 

        self.frame_content = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_content.pack()

        ttk.Label(self.frame_content, text = 'Root Directory:').grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = 4)

        ttk.Label(self.frame_content, text = 'Key Phrases:').grid(row = 2, column = 0) 

        self.entry_rootdirectory = ttk.Entry(self.frame_content, width = 35, font = ('Arial', 10))
        self.text_keyphrases = Text(self.frame_content, width = 35, height = 5, font = ('Arial', 10))


        self.entry_rootdirectory.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self.text_keyphrases.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        ttk.Button(self.frame_content, text = 'Submit', command = self.submit).grid(row = 5, column = 0, pady = 5)
        ttk.Button(self.frame_content, text = 'Clear', command = self.clear).grid(row = 5, column = 1, pady = 5)


    def submit(self):
        #My code that attents to bind to the python script
        print(versionFilter(self.entry_rootdirectory.get(), self.text_keyphrases.get(1.0, 'end'))) #trying to get the users input and pass them as parameters for the function, and print out the results afterwards  
        self.clear()
        messagebox.showinfo(title = "Search Requested", message = "Search Submitted!")


    def clear(self):
        self.entry_rootdirectory.delete(0, 'end')
        #self.text_filetypes.delete(1.0, 'end')
        self.text_keyphrases.delete(1.0, 'end') 

def main():

    root = Tk()
    feedback = Feedback(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

## My Python Function

```
import os

def myFunction(rootdir, keyPhrases):

    path = r"rootdir" #The root directory being passed as a parameter, this is where the key phrases are being searched from 

    key_phrases = ["keyPhrases"] #Passed as a parameter, this is the key phrases users input to find corresponding lines in the directory that contains the key phrases

    # This for loop allows all sub directories and files to be searched
    for (path, subdirs, files) in os.walk(path): 
        files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.txt') or f.endswith('.log')] # Specify here the format of files you hope to search from (ex: ".txt" or ".log")
        files.sort() # file is sorted list

        files = [os.path.join(path, name) for name in files] # Joins the path and the name, so the files can be opened and scanned by the open() function

        # The following for loop searches all files with the selected format
        for filename in files:

                # Opens the individual files and to read their lines
                with open(filename) as f:
                    f = f.readlines()

                # The following loop scans for the key phrases entered by the user in every line of the files searched, and stores the lines that match into the "important" array
                for line in f:
                    for phrase in key_phrases: 
                        if phrase in line:
                            return print(line)
                            break

    # Prints the selected lines after searching the desired files of the entire directory
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that the values you're passing into  your function are what you think they are? Have you verified your code is finding all of the right directories, and all of the files in the directories?

Comment: You don't return anything from `versionFilter` so python returns the default `None`. Is that where the problem is?

Comment: Thank you guys for the responses. I have changed my "print(line)" in my python function to a "return print(line)," but unfortunately it is still returning none. When I manually enter the directory and key phrases to my "path" and "key_phrases" arrays I'm able to get the desired results, so I think it's capable of finding all the right directories. I'm guessing I'm not passing the values properly, but I'm not too sure how I may debug that. Please let me know what you think, once again, thanks so much!

Comment: `return print(line)` will also return none. You need to `return line`